# Where to Seed Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, seed

Using MVC.NET, Entity Framework Code First it appears that I can seed my database in two places. In a custom Initialiser of the Data Context or in the Seed method of the Migrations configuration class.

Is this correct, which should I use?

Comment: Here's a hint: which method is called "Seed"?

Comment: No need for sarcasm, the two Seed() methods are very different. The one on the initializer is only run when the database gets recreated so I use that to seed basic data like my system data and test users. The migration seed runs every time you do an update-database and you would commonly use AddOrUpdate commands to migrate new objects. https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Comment: hmmm ... a mixed welcome to the site. Thanks Steve, the link was helpful.